# Arduino IDE display DEBUG PORT Serial1 output

Tags: arduino-ide, python

How can I display / capture Arduino IDE's `Serial1` output?
Can I display it using `Arduino IDE` or using a script in `Python`?

This python script ([courtesy of Chad G](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/67229/30341)) works for the Serial:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import serial 
import sys

if len(sys.argv)<2:
    print("Please give serial port number")
    exit()
port=sys.argv[1]
ser= serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB'+port,9600,timeout=5)

while True:
    try:
    stringMe = str(ser.readline().strip())
    if len(stringMe)>3:
        print(stringMe)

    except:
    print(sys.exc_info())
    ser.close()
    exit()
```

called as (for USB0):

```
python3 Arduino/tools/multiMonitor/monitorUsb1.py 0
```

or, if I want to save to a log file:

```
python3 Arduino/tools/multiMonitor/monitorUsb1.py 0 >> Arduino/tools/multiMonitor/log/usb00.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Serial1` (on most Arduino boards that have `Serial1`) is connected to a pair of pins on the GPIO headers and nowhere else.

To get it to your computer you will have to feed those TX and RX pins through a USB to TTL UART (FT232, CP2102, etc) adaptor.

From there on in it's exactly the same as using `Serial` but of course with a different device name.